# How to fetch classified objects with jpa(hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

there are 3 classes here:

```
abstract class AbstractClass{@Column("type") public int type;......}
class A extends AbstractClass{......}
class B extends AbstractClass{......}
```

in database, when type=1 means A and type=2 means B. So how can i fetch these objects as AbstractClass, and the concrete class is A when type=1 and B when type=2 ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your database structure. If you are using one table for the whole class hierarchy, check out Hibernates documentation on [table per class hierarchy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1212). If you are using one table to store the common fields in the AbstractClass and a table for each subclass you can have a look at the documentation on [Mixing table per class hierarchy with table per subclass](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1248). In both cases it comes down to defining a descriminator (in your case the type column).

Comment: My pleasure. Don't forget to report back on how it went and award the answer/upvote where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "one table per class hierarchy" inheritance mapping, described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1212). The explicit mapping of the discriminator column is possible, but not mandatory.